# GSC Structured Data error for "Missing: homeLocation"

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, rich-snippets, structured-data

Although we didn't do any changes, this new error appeared in the GSC Structured Data section:

[image: Error Type - Missing: homeLocation. This property is missing in the html markup. This can prevent the rich snippet from appearing.]

I don't really get what it means. There are many fields for Schema.org, is `homeLocation` suddenly a required field? Does that make any sense?

Comment: To which URL links "Learn more"?

Comment: Just to pages without that field (none of my pages has that field). As an example: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?url=http://klear.com/profile/amanziwaterpark#url=http%3A%2F%2Fklear.com%2Fprofile%2Famanziwaterpark

Comment: I wonder if you can see somehow to which rich snippet it refers for this error? (I don’t use GSC) -- Schema.org does not require any properties, so errors like these are typically just "warnings" (that you don’t get a specific search result feature, because of missing properties). But AFAIK Google has no rich snippet for `Person` that could make use of `homeLocation` … their testing tool also doesn’t report this property as missing (like your example shows).

Comment: It's an error from Google https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/rnyX-Gi5EGQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a known glitch on Google's side of things which has now been addressed. It was temporarily being marked as a required field now it has been corrected with Google as `homeLocation` is not required. It may take some time for the errors to disappear from the error report but this has been resolved by Google.

Thanks @mayrop for the link.

Source: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/rnyX-Gi5EGQ